# How to use adminlte in React

Tags: reactjs, adminlte

Using React I had used adminlte by setting it in index file and copying the adminlte files but works fine but is slow to load.

I want to use adminlte-react from npm package but if go to install it fails. Error or if installed doesn't run properly. Anyone can help how to properly integrate it or give an example in which it will run because one example used not running and could not find more.

Please help.

Comment: Improved formatting a bit. Please try not to write what's not important. Your question was one huge sentence.

Comment: Add debugging details

Comment: Its not exactly a problem to debug but am searching a method to add adminlte to react project like properly